# update data problem

Tags: apache-2.2, php, linux

I would like to inform you about the another problem of the server. When we are updating the records, it updates the records in the database but when we want to access it on the browser through the frontend application of php files it is not displaying the updated records immediately. It takes the time of 15-20 minutes or more or sometimes we closes the browser and open the another browser then the updated records display there. I have already deleted the browser cache but the problem is still remains. I have checked this in the different different broswers like IE 6.0,7.0, chrome, safari, mozilla but unable to find the solution.

please suggest me what is the problem with the server? please check this url : http://www.nicee.org/trial/view.php
regards

rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you install xcache , mod_cache or something like that on the server?